# What exactly is a reentrant function?

Tags: recursion, thread-safety, reentrancy

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435541/is-this-function-reentrant/1435561#1435561) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856823/threadsafe-vs-re-entrant/856856#856856) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435541/is-this-function-reentrant/1435577#1435577) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441351/what-is-a-re-entrant-parser/2441401#2441401), the definition of reentrance is quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29):

> A computer program or routine is
> described as reentrant if it can be
> ***safely*** called again before its
> previous invocation has been completed
> (i.e it can be safely executed
> concurrently). To be reentrant, a
> computer program or routine:
>
> 1. Must hold no static (or global)
>    non-constant data.
> 2. Must not return the address to
>    static (or global) non-constant
>    data.
> 3. Must work only on the data provided
>    to it by the caller.
> 4. Must not rely on locks to singleton
>    resources.
> 5. Must not modify its own code (unless
>    executing in its own unique thread
>    storage)
> 6. Must not call non-reentrant computer
>    programs or routines.

How is ***safely*** defined?

If a program can be ***safely executed concurrently***, does it always mean that it is reentrant?

What exactly is the common thread between the six points mentioned that I should keep in mind while checking my code for reentrant capabilities?

Also,

1. Are all recursive functions reentrant?
2. Are all thread-safe functions reentrant?
3. Are all recursive and thread-safe functions reentrant?

---

While writing this question, one thing comes to mind:
Are the terms like **reentrance** and **thread safety** absolute at all i.e. do they have fixed concrete definitions? For, if they are not, this question is not very meaningful.

Comment: Actually, I disagree with #2 in  the first list. You can return a address to whatever you like from a re-entrant function - the limitation is on what you do with that address in the calling code.

Comment: @Neil But as the writer of the reentrant function can't control what the caller surely surely they must not return an address to static (or global) non-constant data for it to be truely reentrant?

Comment: @drelihan It is not the responsibility of the writer of ANY function (reentrant or not) to control what a caller does with a returned value. They should certainly say what the caller CAN do with it, but if the caller chooses to do something else - tough luck to the caller.

Comment: "thread-safe" is meaningless unless you also specify what the threads are doing, and what the expected effect of their doings is. But perhaps that should be a separate question.

Comment: I take safely to mean, the behavior is well defined and deterministic regardless of scheduling.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

### 1. How is *safely* defined?

Semantically. In this case, this is not a hard-defined term. It just mean "You can do that, without risk".

### 2. If a program can be safely executed concurrently, does it always mean that it is reentrant?

No.

For example, let's have a C++ function that takes both a lock, and a callback as a parameter:

```
#include <mutex>

typedef void (*callback)();
std::mutex m;

void foo(callback f)
{
    m.lock();
    // use the resource protected by the mutex

    if (f) {
        f();
    }

    // use the resource protected by the mutex
    m.unlock();
}
```

Another function could well need to lock the same mutex:

```
void bar()
{
    foo(nullptr);
}
```

At first sight, everything seems ok… But wait:

```
int main()
{
    foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

If the lock on mutex is not recursive, then here's what will happen, in the main thread:

1. `main` will call `foo`.
2. `foo` will acquire the lock.
3. `foo` will call `bar`, which will call `foo`.
4. the 2nd `foo` will try to acquire the lock, fail and wait for it to be released.
5. Deadlock.
6. Oops…

Ok, I cheated, using the callback thing. But it's easy to imagine more complex pieces of code having a similar effect.

### 3. What exactly is the common thread between the six points mentioned that I should keep in mind while checking my code for reentrant capabilities?

You can *smell* a problem if your function has/gives access to a modifiable persistent resource, or has/gives access to a function that *smells*.

(*Ok, 99% of our code should smell, then… See last section to handle that…*)

So, studying your code, one of those points should alert you:

1. The function has a state (i.e. access a global variable, or even a data member)
2. This function can be called by multiple threads, or could appear twice in the stack while the process is executing (i.e. the function could call itself, directly or indirectly). Function taking callbacks as parameters *smell* a lot.

Note that non-reentrancy is viral : A function that could call a possible non-reentrant function cannot be considered reentrant.

Note, too, that C++ methods *smell* because they have access to `this`, so you should study the code to be sure they have no funny interaction.

### 4.1. Are all recursive functions reentrant?

No.

In multithreaded cases, a recursive function accessing a shared resource could be called by multiple threads at the same moment, resulting in bad/corrupted data.

In singlethreaded cases, a recursive function could use a non-reentrant function (like the infamous `strtok`), or use global data without handling the fact the data is already in use. So your function is recursive because it calls itself directly or indirectly, but it can still be *recursive-unsafe*.

### 4.2. Are all thread-safe functions reentrant?

In the example above, I showed how an apparently threadsafe function was not reentrant. OK, I cheated because of the callback parameter. But then, there are multiple ways to deadlock a thread by having it acquire twice a non-recursive lock.

### 4.3. Are all recursive and thread-safe functions reentrant?

I would say "yes" if by "recursive" you mean "recursive-safe".

If you can guarantee that a function can be called simultaneously by multiple threads, and can call itself, directly or indirectly, without problems, then it is reentrant.

The problem is evaluating this guarantee… ^_^

### 5. Are the terms like reentrance and thread safety absolute at all, i.e. do they have fixed concrete definitions?

I believe they do, but then, evaluating a function is thread-safe or reentrant can be difficult. This is why I used the term *smell* above: You can find a function is not reentrant, but it could be difficult to be sure a complex piece of code is reentrant

### 6. An example

Let's say you have an object, with one method that needs to use a resource:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    P * p;

    void foo()
    {
        if (this->p == nullptr)
        {
            this->p = new P();
        }

        // lots of code, some using this->p

        if (this->p != nullptr)
        {
            delete this->p;
            this->p = nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

The first problem is that if somehow this function is called recursively (i.e. this function calls itself, directly or indirectly), the code will probably crash, because `this->p` will be deleted at the end of the last call, and still probably be used before the end of the first call.

Thus, this code is not *recursive-safe*.

We could use a reference counter to correct this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    size_t c;
    P * p;

    void foo()
    {
        if (c == 0)
        {
            this->p = new P();
        }

        ++c;
        // lots of code, some using this->p
        --c;

        if (c == 0)
        {
            delete this->p;
            this->p = nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

This way, the code becomes recursive-safe… But it is still not reentrant because of multithreading issues: We must be sure the modifications of `c` and of `p` will be done atomically, using a **recursive** mutex (not all mutexes are recursive):

```
#include <mutex>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::recursive_mutex m;
    size_t c;
    P * p;

    void foo()
    {
        m.lock();

        if (c == 0)
        {
            this->p = new P();
        }

        ++c;
        m.unlock();
        // lots of code, some using this->p
        m.lock();
        --c;

        if (c == 0)
        {
            delete this->p;
            this->p = nullptr;
        }

        m.unlock();
    }
};
```

And of course, this all assumes the `lots of code` is itself reentrant, including the use of `p`.

And the code above is not even remotely [exception-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrahams_guarantees), but this is another story… ^_^

### 7. Hey 99% of our code is not reentrant!

It is quite true for spaghetti code. But if you partition correctly your code, you will avoid reentrancy problems.

#### 7.1. Make sure all functions have NO state

They must only use the parameters, their own local variables, other functions without state, and return copies of the data if they return at all.

#### 7.2. Make sure your object is "recursive-safe"

An object method has access to `this`, so it shares a state with all the methods of the same instance of the object.

So, make sure the object can be used at one point in the stack (i.e. calling method A), and then, at another point (i.e. calling method B), without corrupting the whole object. Design your object to make sure that upon exiting a method, the object is stable and correct (no dangling pointers, no contradicting data members, etc.).

#### 7.3. Make sure all your objects are correctly encapsulated

No one else should have access to their internal data:

```
    // bad
    int & MyObject::getCounter()
    {
        return this->counter;
    }

    // good
    int MyObject::getCounter()
    {
        return this->counter;
    }

    // good, too
    void MyObject::getCounter(int & p_counter)
    {
        p_counter = this->counter;
    }
```

Even returning a const reference could be dangerous if the user retrieves the address of the data, as some other portion of the code could modify it without the code holding the const reference being told.

#### 7.4. Make sure the user knows your object is not thread-safe

Thus, the user is responsible to use mutexes to use an object shared between threads.

The objects from the STL are designed to be not thread-safe (because of performance issues), and thus, if a user want to share a `std::string` between two threads, the user must protect its access with concurrency primitives;

#### 7.5. Make sure your thread-safe code is recursive-safe

This means using recursive mutexes if you believe the same resource can be used twice by the same thread.

Comment: To quibble a bit, I actually think in this case "safety" is defined - it means that the function will act only on variables provided - ie, it's shorthand for the definition quote below it. And point is that this might not imply other ideas of safety.

Comment: Did you miss passing in the mutex in the first example?

Comment: @paercebal: your example is wrong. You do not actually need to bother with the callback, a simple recursion would have the same problem if there is one, however the only problem is you forgot to say exactly where the lock is allocated.

Comment: @Yttrill: I assume you're talking about the first example. I used the "callback" because, by essence, a callback smells. Of course, a recursive function would have the same problem, but usually, one can easily analyse a function and its recursive nature, an thus, detect if it's reentrant or it's ok for recursivity. The callback, in the other hands, means that the author of the function calling the callback has no info whatsoever about what's the callback doing, so this author can find it difficult to make sure his/her function is reentrant. This is this difficulty I wanted to show.

Comment: @Yttrill: As for the "however the only problem is you forgot to say exactly where the lock is allocated", I believe you missed the point (I did modify the code to add mutex declaration). Anyway, assuming the mutex was correctly initialized (if not, you have other problems than reentrancy) the first code is Ok as long as it won't be called again in the same stack OR the mutex is recursive. But if the mutex is NOT recursive, AND the function called is recursively called (directly, or through a callback, as in the example), then you're screwed, and the second lock will stop the stack's execution.

Comment: It's quite a dilemma here: the function calls itself. A function is not reentrant if it calls nonreentrant functions. So it is reentrant if itself is reentrant and is not if itself is not. Recursive magic.

Comment: *"Ok, I cheated, using the Callback thing. "* What made you say this? Isn't using callback a valid act?

Comment: @Anisha Kaul : `Isn't using callback a valid act?` Yes it is, even if it is a *smelly* one (giving a callback, lambda, etc. as a parameter is somewhat giving the control on the stack to the user of your code, meaning that this user could screw it up without you being able to do anything. My "cheat" was more about the oversimplicity of my example, which is bordersome absurd (calling a function A, and giving it A as a callback)... :-) ... I see little code in real life doing that... :-)

Comment: If a function acquires a lock during some parts of its operation, and calls itself recursively during times it does not hold the lock, would not such a function be thread-safe and recursive but not reentrant?

Comment: The first example does not compile. The type of the function `myFunction` is not compatible with the type `MyCallback`. I think an example with signal handler could better illustrate your point without '**cheating**'.

Comment: @Gab是好人 : I corrected the first example. Thanks! A signal handler would come with its own problems, distinct from reentrancy, as usually, when a signal is raised, you can't really do anything beyond changing a specifically declared global variable.

Comment: Two remarks: 1. "This way, the code becomes recursive-safe… But it is still not reentrant because of multithreading issues" So you are stating that reentrancy implies thread-safety, which contradicts the "Reentrant but not thread-safe" Wikipedia [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)#Reentrant_but_not_thread-safe). 2. Your last example with the recursive lock is multithread-safe but not *single* thread-safe, that is it is not signal-safe, which is the Wikipedia [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) for reentrancy. So have you a reference?

Comment: Why should most thread-safe code be re-entrant? If it is made thread-safe by synchronization (using mutex) then this cannot be re-entrant because locking the same mutex twice is a deadlock and in general the mutex is a global variable anyways.

Comment: Reading this, it looks like you always these properties automatically by using "pure" functions from "functional programming". What's the set relationship between pure and re-entrant functions?

Answer (score 24):

"Safely" is defined exactly as the common sense dictates - it means "doing its thing correctly without interfering with other things". The six points you cite quite clearly express the requirements to achieve that.

The answers to your 3 questions is 3× "no".

---

*Are all recursive functions reentrant?*

**NO!**

Two simultaneous invocations of a recursive function can easily screw up each other, if 
they access the same global/static data, for example.

---

*Are all thread-safe functions reentrant?*

**NO!**

A function is thread-safe if it doesn't malfunction if called concurrently. But this can be achieved e.g. by using a mutex to block the execution of the second invocation until the first finishes, so only one invocation works at a time. Reentrancy means *executing concurrently without interfering with other invocations*.

---

*Are all recursive and thread-safe functions reentrant?*

**NO!**

See above.

Answer (score 18):

The common thread:

Is the behavior well defined if the routine is called while it is interrupted?

If you have a function like this:

```
int add( int a , int b ) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Then it is not dependent upon any external state.  The behavior is well defined.

If you have a function like this:

```
int add_to_global( int a ) {
  return gValue += a;
}
```

The result is not well defined on multiple threads.  Information could be lost if the timing was just wrong.

The simplest form of a reentrant function is something that operates exclusively on the arguments passed and constant values.  Anything else takes special handling or, often, is not reentrant.  And of course the arguments must not reference mutable globals.

Answer (score 8):

Now I have to elaborate on my previous comment. @paercebal answer is incorrect. In the example code didn't anyone notice that the mutex which as supposed to be parameter wasn't actually passed in?

I dispute the conclusion, I assert: for a function to be safe in the presence of concurrency it must be re-entrant. Therefore concurrent-safe (usually written thread-safe) implies re-entrant.

Neither thread safe nor re-entrant have anything to say about arguments: we're talking about concurrent execution of the function, which can still be unsafe if inappropriate parameters are used.

For example, memcpy() is thread-safe and re-entrant (usually). Obviously it will not work as expected if called with pointers to the same targets from two different threads. That's the point of the SGI definition, placing the onus on the client to ensure accesses to the same data structure are synchronised by the client.

It is important to understand that in general it is **nonsense** to have thread-safe operation include the parameters. If you've done any database programming you will understand. The concept of what is "atomic" and might be protected by a mutex or some other technique is necessarily a user concept: processing a transaction on a database can require multiple un-interrupted modifications. Who can say which ones need to be kept in sync but the client programmer?

The point is that "corruption" doesn't have to be messing up the memory on your computer with unserialised writes: corruption can still occur even if all individual operations are serialised. It follows that when you're asking if a function is thread-safe, or re-entrant, the question means for all appropriately separated arguments: using coupled arguments does not constitute a counter-example.

There are many programming systems out there: Ocaml is one, and I think Python as well, which have lots of non-reentrant code in them, but which uses a global lock to interleave thread acesss. These systems are not re-entrant and they're not thread-safe or concurrent-safe, they operate safely simply because they prevent concurrency globally.

A good example is malloc. It is not re-entrant and not thread-safe. This is because it has to access a global resource (the heap). Using locks doesn't make it safe: it's definitely not re-entrant. If the interface to malloc had be design properly it would be possible to make it re-entrant and thread-safe:

```
malloc(heap*, size_t);
```

Now it can be safe because it transfers the responsibility for serialising shared access to a single heap to the client. In particular no work is required if there are separate heap objects. If a common heap is used, the client has to serialise access. Using a lock **inside** the function is not enough: just consider a malloc locking a heap* and then a signal comes along and calls malloc on the same pointer: deadlock: the signal can't proceed, and the client can't either because it is interrupted.

Generally speaking, locks do not make things thread-safe .. they actually destroy safety by inappropriately trying to manage a resource that is owned by the client. Locking has to be done by the object manufacturer, thats the only code that knows how many objects are created and how they will be used.

Comment: "Therefore concurrent-safe (usually written thread-safe) implies re-entrant." This contradicts the "Thread-safe but not reentrant" Wikipedia [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)#Thread-safe_but_not_reentrant).

Answer (score 4):

The "common thread" (pun intended!?) amongst the points listed is that the function must not do anything that would affect the behaviour of any recursive or concurrent calls to the same function.

So for example static data is an issue because it is owned by all threads; if one call modifies a static variable the all threads use the modified data thus affecting their behaviour.  Self modifying code (although rarely encountered, and in some cases prevented) would be a problem, because although there are multiple thread, there is only one copy of the code; the code is essential static data too.

Essentially to be re-entrant, each thread must be able to use the function as if it were the only user, and that is not the case if one thread can affect the behaviour of another in a non-deterministic manner.  Primarily this involves each thread having either separate or constant data that the function works on.

All that said, point (1) is not necessarily true; for example, you might legitimately and by design use a static variable to retain a recursion count to guard against excessive recursion or to profile an algorithm.

A thread-safe function need not be reentrant; it may achieve thread safety by specifically preventing reentrancy with a lock, and point (6) says that such a function is not reentrant.  Regarding point (6), a function that calls a thread-safe function that locks is not safe for use in recursion (it will dead-lock), and is therefore not said to be reentrant, though it may nonetheless safe for concurrency, and would still be re-entrant in the sense that multiple threads can have their program-counters in such a function simultaneously (just not with the locked region).  May be this helps to distinguish thread-safety from reentarncy (or maybe adds to your confusion!).

Answer (score 3):

The answers your "Also" questions are "No", "No" and "No". Just because a function is recursive and/or thread safe it doesn't make it re-entrant.

Each of these type of function can fail on all the points you quote. (Though I'm not 100% certain of point 5).

Answer (score 2):

- non reentrant function means that there will be a static context, maintained by function. when first time entering, there will be create new context for you. and next entering, you don't send more parameter for that, for convenient to token analyze, . e.g. strtok in c. if you have not clear the context, there might be some errors.

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

- on the contrary of non-reentrant, reentrant function means calling function in anytime will get the same result without side effect. because there is none of context.
- in the view of thread safe, it just means there is only one modification for public variable in current time, in current process. so you should add lock guard to ensure just one change for public field in one time.
- so thread safety and reentrant are two different things in different views.reentrant function safety says you should clear context before next time for context analyze. thread safety says you should keep visit public field order.

Answer (score 1):

The terms "Thread-safe" and "re-entrant" mean only and exactly what their definitions say. "Safe" in this context means *only* what the definition you quote below it says.

"Safe" here certainly doesn't mean safe in the broader sense that calling a given function in a given context won't totally hose your application. Altogether, a function might reliably produce a desired effect in your multi-threaded application but not qualify as either re-entrant or thread-safe according to the definitions. Oppositely, you can call re-entrant functions in ways that will produce a variety of undesired, unexpected and/or unpredictable effects in your multi-threaded application.

Recursive function can be anything and Re-entrant has a stronger definition than thread-safe so the answers to your numbered questions are all no.

Reading the definition of re-entrant, one might summarize it as meaning a function which will not modify any anything beyond what you call it to modify. But you shouldn't rely on only the summary.

Multi-threaded programming is just [extremely difficult](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2008/01/30/why-threading-is-hard.aspx) in the general case. Knowing which part of one's code re-entrant is only a part of this challenge. Thread safety is not additive. Rather than trying to piece together re-entrant functions, it's better to use an overall [thread-safe](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html) [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) and use this pattern to guide your use of *every* thread and shared resources in the your program.