# Are static member functions reentrant?

Tags: c++, reentrancy

Like the title says:

If I have a class with a static member function, which by itself contains no static variables, can I consider the member function reentrant?

Comment: No.  It could be doing anything.

Comment: It depends, what other variables/functions does it touch or call, e.g. globals etc.

Comment: Could be, but not necessarily. What if it's calling other non-reentrant code? What if it's modifying static member variables (not defined in the function itself)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799023/what-exactly-is-a-reentrant-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static member functions are no different from namespace-scope functions (or even member functions) with respect to reentrancy. They are not predisposed either way, it depends entirely on what the function does inside.

Answer (score 5):

The rules for Reentrancy laid out in the [Wikipedia article on Reentrancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) are as follows:

- Reentrant code may not hold any static (or global) non-constant data.
- Reentrant code may not modify its own code.
- Reentrant code may not call non-reentrant computer programs or routines.

so as long as the member function follows those rules it should be ok.

The article [Use reentrant functions for safer signal handling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-reent/) I feel gives a slightly better desciption:

> A reentrant function is one that can be used by more than one task
>   concurrently without fear of data corruption. Conversely, a
>   non-reentrant function is one that cannot be shared by more than one
>   task unless mutual exclusion to the function is ensured either by
>   using a semaphore or by disabling interrupts during critical sections
>   of code. A reentrant function can be interrupted at any time and
>   resumed at a later time without loss of data. Reentrant functions
>   either use local variables or protect their data when global variables
>   are used.
>
> A reentrant function:
>
> - Does not hold static data over successive calls
> - Does not return a pointer to static data; all data is provided by the caller of the function
> - Uses local data or ensures protection of global data by making a local copy of it
> - Must not call any non-reentrant functions

and then goes on to explain how this differs from thread-safety before going the article fully.

Answer (score 0):

If your static member function contains only auto variables you could consider it re-entrant.