# Properly update class members

Tags: c++, multithreading, ncurses

I am trying to write a program solving 5 dining philosophers problem. I am on the beginning, so for now I want every philosopher to just think, eat, without any synchronization, looking at forks etc. This is what I wrote:

```
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <fork.hpp>

class dining_philosophers {
public:
    // std::vector<philosopher> philosophers;
    std::array<fork, 5> forks;
    // ui u;
    dining_philosophers();
    std::atomic<bool> ready{false};
};

dining_philosophers::dining_philosophers() {}

class philosopher {
public:
    dining_philosophers &table;
    // ui &u;
    fork &left_fork;
    fork &right_fork;
    std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device{}()};
    int state = -1;
    int progress = 0;
    int id;
    std::thread t;
    philosopher();
    philosopher(int _id, dining_philosophers &table_ref, fork l, fork r)
        : id(_id), left_fork(l), right_fork(r), table(table_ref),
          t(&philosopher::live, this) {}
    void live();
    void eat();
    void think();
    void wait_for_forks();
    void release_forks();
};

void philosopher::live() {
    while (!table.ready) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    while (true) {
        think();
        // wait_for_forks();
        eat();
        // release_forks();
    }
}

void philosopher::think() {
    state = 0;
    int part = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(15, 25)(rng);
    int thinkingTime = part * 200; // in miliseconds
    for (auto i = 0; i < part; i++) {
        double p = (double)i / (double)part;
        progress = p * 100;
        // std::thread t(&ui::update_state, &u, id, "thinking", progress);
        // u.update_state(id, "thinking", progress);
        // t.join();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}

void philosopher::eat() {
    state = 1;
    int part = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(15, 25)(rng);
    int thinkingTime = part * 200; // in miliseconds
    for (auto i = 0; i < part; i++) {
        double p = (double)i / (double)part;
        progress = p * 100;
        // std::thread t(&ui::update_state, &u, id, "thinking", progress);
        // u.update_state(id, "thinking", progress);
        // t.join();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}
```

`class fork` is just empty, I wrote it to use it later.

Now I need to print some information about what's going on using ncurses. I thought about making it like this: I have a global vector of philosophers. Every 200ms my other thread using `ui::update()` function checks for philosophers members, like id, state and progress and prints it out. I wrote something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <dining_philosophers.hpp>

std::vector<philosopher> philosophers;

class ui {
private:
    int row;
    int col;
    std::mutex m;

public:
    ui();
    ~ui();
    void print_initial_state();
    void update_state(int id, const char *state, int progress);
    void update();
};

ui::ui() {
    initscr();
    // noecho();
    start_color();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, col, row);
}

ui::~ui() { endwin(); }

void ui::update() {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    while (true) {
        for (auto &phil : philosophers) {
            int id = phil.id;
            int state = phil.state;
            int progress = phil.progress;
            move(y + id - 1, 0);
            clrtoeol();
            move(y + id - 1, x);
            printw("Philosopher %d is %d, progress: %d%%", id, state, progress);
            refresh();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}

int main() {
    dining_philosophers table;
    ui u;
    // std::vector<philosopher> philosophers;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        philosophers.push_back(
            philosopher(i + 1, table, table.forks[i], table.forks[i + 1]));
    }
    philosophers.push_back(
        philosopher(5, table, table.forks[4], table.forks[0]));
    // std::thread t{[&]() {}};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    table.ready = true;
    std::thread t1(&ui::update, &u);
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    // t.join();
    t1.join();
    for (auto &p : philosophers) {
        p.t.join();
    }
}
```

I know I don't have a proper thread closing, for now I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The problem is that ncurses for five philosophers prints:

```
Philosopher 1 is -1, progress: 0%
Philosopher 2 is -1, progress: 0%
```

and so on. If in update function I would do `philosophers[0].progress++`, it would start to increment the progress. So I guess the problem is that if the thread in philosopher (`live()` function) changes something, the change does not appear in the global vector. Is there a way to change that behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Windows - one modified by thread random output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545588/two-windows-one-modified-by-thread-random-output)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. Its not a ncurses problem

Answer (score 0):

Process of creating threads is your issue.

```
for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    philosophers.push_back(philosopher(i + 1, table, table.forks[i], table.forks[i + 1]));
}
```

in above code you create `philosopher` object which is inserted into vector. In constructor of `philosopher` you create thread

```
    philosopher(int _id, dining_philosophers &table_ref, fork l, fork r)
    : id(_id), left_fork(l), right_fork(r), table(table_ref),
      t(&philosopher::live, this) {} // <<<<<---------------------
```

so `t` thread was created and it took as thread function - `live` method, and this method is being called on `this` object.

After calling

```
philosophers.push_back(philosopher(i + 1, table, table.forks[i], table.forks[i + 1]));
```

temporary object `philosopher` in `push_back` method is moved, so moved object gets new value of `this` pointer. While calling `push_back` method reallocation of memory occurs too ,so all created objectes are moved. This way of constructing objects is issue - thread function refers to object which doesn't exist, object was moved so its `this` pointer is invalid.

For me you should create all objects and then you can start thread.

1) remove

```
   t(&philosopher::live, this) {}
```

from constructor

2) add new method in `philosopher` class to start thread

```
void startTask () {
    t = thread(&philosopher::live,this);
}
```

3) create and start threads

```
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    philosophers.push_back(
        philosopher(i + 1, table, table.forks[i], table.forks[i + 1]));
}
philosophers.push_back(
    philosopher(5, table, table.forks[4], table.forks[0]));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   philosophers[i].startTask();
```

And the last issue, your current constructor looks like

```
philosopher(int _id, dining_philosophers &table_ref, fork l, fork r)
    : id(_id), left_fork(l), right_fork(r), table(table_ref),
```

`left_fork` and `right_fork` are references, now you bind reference to temporary objects - `l` and `r`, change it to

```
philosopher(int _id, dining_philosophers &table_ref, fork& l, fork& r)
    : id(_id), left_fork(l), right_fork(r), table(table_ref),
```