# Avoid memory reallocation on given example

Tags: c++, optimization, allocation, ros

The function gets called very frequently, so I try to lower memory-reallocation etc. What bothers me, is the `vector` and `int`, though I cant move them outside the function otherwise I get `std::bad_alloc`. So far I have:

```
void callbString(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    vector<string> cbstrVec;
    int cbtype;

    //get string and split into vector
    string str = (msg->data.c_str());
    if(str.empty()) return;
    str.erase(0,1);
    boost::split(cbstrVec, str, boost::is_any_of(" "));
    stringstream(cbstrVec[2])>>cbtype;
    c.setvec(cbstrVec,cbtype); //takes (vector<string>,int) 
}
```

Comment: You needn't worry about the int, there is no real allocation for it. Besides, the vector, string and stringstream objects are going to be far more heavy-weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you profiled the application? and is that your code REALLY the bottle neck?** If you have... then

Well, if you are using a C++11 compiler you could do this, if you don't have a C++11 compiler, remove the `thread_local` but then you'll have to take care of [reentrancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799023/what-exactly-is-a-reentrant-function#) if there is a chance that that routine will be called in a multithreaded code

```
void callbString(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    static thread_local vector<string> cbstrVec;
    static thread_local std::string str;

    int cbtype;  //int is super cheap

    cbstrVec.clear();

    //get string and split into vector
    str = (msg->data.c_str());
    if(str.empty()) return;
    str.erase(0,1);
    boost::split(cbstrVec, str, boost::is_any_of(" "));
    stringstream(cbstrVec[2])>>cbtype;
    //c.setvec(cbstrVec,cbtype); //takes (vector<string>,int) 
    c.setvec(std::move(cbstrVec),cbtype); //takes (vector<string>,int) 
}
```

`cbstrVec` and `str` will have their memory reused since `cbstrVec.clear()` doesn't really deallocate all the memory allocated by the vector and reassigning `str` will reuse the internal storage in a good STL implementation

Comment: I think you should also move cbstrVec at last line if setvec accept rvalues.

Comment: @PustovalovDmitry Thanks, I just updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: If the function has call by reference is the  `std::move` still necessary  `setvec(vector<string>& strVec, int& type) ` .

Comment: @Julianemailde ...Correct... true :-)

Comment: sidenote: std::move is C++11 also I use C++98, How to approach it there?

Comment: Its not a problem there since its by reference... but if you are still going to copy out `strVec` ... you could just use the old school swap idiom //Example `vector<string> mkx;   mkx.swap(vecStr);` ... :-)